# Groupby day to show True if identical consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following DataFrame.  How do I add a new column showing `True` in next row when two consecutive `"y"` are seen in a single day in the `val` column (else `False`).

- Each day resets the logic.
- Essentially looking for two consecutive "y" in a single day then if next row is same day add a `True`.

**Data**

```
df_so = pd.DataFrame(
    {"val": ["y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n"]},
    index=pd.date_range(start="1/1/2018", periods=13, freq="8h"),
)

df_so

                   val
2018-01-01 00:00:00  y
2018-01-01 08:00:00  y
2018-01-01 16:00:00  y
2018-01-02 00:00:00  n
2018-01-02 08:00:00  y
2018-01-02 16:00:00  y
2018-01-03 00:00:00  y
2018-01-03 08:00:00  y
2018-01-03 16:00:00  n
2018-01-04 00:00:00  n
2018-01-04 08:00:00  y
2018-01-04 16:00:00  y
2018-01-05 00:00:00  n
```

**Desired output** would look like this:

```
                   val  desired_col
2018-01-01 00:00:00 y   False
2018-01-01 08:00:00 y   False
2018-01-01 16:00:00 y   True
2018-01-02 00:00:00 n   False
2018-01-02 08:00:00 y   False
2018-01-02 16:00:00 y   False
2018-01-03 00:00:00 y   False
2018-01-03 08:00:00 y   False
2018-01-03 16:00:00 n   True
2018-01-04 00:00:00 n   False
2018-01-04 08:00:00 y   False
2018-01-04 16:00:00 y   False
2018-01-05 00:00:00 n   False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby().rolling()` here:

```
target = 2
days = df_so.index.normalize()
df_so['out'] = (df_so['val'].eq('y')
               .groupby(days)
               .rolling(target, min_periods=0).sum()
               .reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
               .groupby(days).shift().eq(target)
          )
```

Or with `groupby().transform`:

```
target = 2
df_so['out'] = (df_so['val'].eq('y')
                    .groupby(df_so.index.normalize())
                    .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(target).sum().shift().eq(target))
               )
```

Output:

```
                    val    out
2018-01-01 00:00:00   y  False
2018-01-01 08:00:00   y  False
2018-01-01 16:00:00   y   True
2018-01-02 00:00:00   n  False
2018-01-02 08:00:00   y  False
2018-01-02 16:00:00   y  False
2018-01-03 00:00:00   y  False
2018-01-03 08:00:00   y  False
2018-01-03 16:00:00   n   True
2018-01-04 00:00:00   n  False
2018-01-04 08:00:00   y  False
2018-01-04 16:00:00   y  False
2018-01-05 00:00:00   n  False
```

Comment: I realise my explanation of the logic was incorrect so have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73707204/groupby-remainder-of-day-to-show-true-if-identical-consecutive-values) as you answered this correctly.