# Groupby remainder of day to show True if identical consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following DataFrame. How do I add a new column showing `True` **for the rest of the day** when two consecutive `"y"` are seen in a single day in the `val` column (else `False`).

- Each day resets the logic.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706077/groupby-day-to-show-true-if-identical-consecutive-values) is close but the `True` should be for each row in this day after condition is seen.

**Code**

```
df_so = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "val": list("yynnnyyynn")
    },
    index=pd.date_range(start="1/1/2018", periods=10, freq="6h"),
)

                   val
2018-01-01 00:00:00 y
2018-01-01 06:00:00 y
2018-01-01 12:00:00 n
2018-01-01 18:00:00 n
2018-01-02 00:00:00 n
2018-01-02 06:00:00 y
2018-01-02 12:00:00 y
2018-01-02 18:00:00 y
2018-01-03 00:00:00 n
2018-01-03 06:00:00 n
```

**Desired output**

```
                    val  out
2018-01-01 00:00:00  y   False
2018-01-01 06:00:00  y   False
2018-01-01 12:00:00  n   True
2018-01-01 18:00:00  n   True
2018-01-02 00:00:00  n   False
2018-01-02 06:00:00  y   False
2018-01-02 12:00:00  y   False
2018-01-02 18:00:00  y   True
2018-01-03 00:00:00  n   False
2018-01-03 06:00:00  n   False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cummax` to check if the condition holds at some point in the past:

```
target = 2
df_so['out'] = (df_so['val'].eq('y')
                    .groupby(df_so.index.normalize())
                    .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(target).sum().shift().eq(target).cummax())
               )
```

Output:

```
                    val    out
2018-01-01 00:00:00   y  False
2018-01-01 06:00:00   y  False
2018-01-01 12:00:00   n   True
2018-01-01 18:00:00   n   True
2018-01-02 00:00:00   n  False
2018-01-02 06:00:00   y  False
2018-01-02 12:00:00   y  False
2018-01-02 18:00:00   y   True
2018-01-03 00:00:00   n  False
2018-01-03 06:00:00   n  False
```